# Pandas Dataframe Question: Apply function add new column with results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': 'a a b c b c'.split(), 'Val': [2,2,6, 4,6, 8]})
df

  label  Val
0     a    2
1     a    2
2     b    6
3     c    4
4     b    6
5     c    8

df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x.mean())

 Val
label     
a      2.0
b      6.0
c      6.0
```

I'd like something like this. Where results are the values divided by the mean of the unique label:

```
label  Val  Results
0     a    2    1
1     a    2    1
2     b    6    1
3     c    4    0.6667
4     b    6    1
5     c    8    1.3333
```

Not entirely sure how to do it. Anyone have an idea?
Tried this but didnt work:

```
df['Results'] = df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, add column `Val` after `groupby` for processing this column:

```
df['Results'] = df.groupby('label')['Val'].apply(lambda x: x/x.mean())
print (df)
  label  Val   Results
0     a    2  1.000000
1     a    2  1.000000
2     b    6  1.000000
3     c    4  0.666667
4     b    6  1.000000
5     c    8  1.333333
```

Another idea for improve performance with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` filled by aggregated values and same size like original columns, so possible divide:

```
df['Results'] = df['Val'].div(df.groupby('label')['Val'].transform('mean'))
```